# How to implement "number of likes" in relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying to setup a database schema where objects can receive likes.
I will often need to access the total number of likes of any given object.

I setup two tables:

```
[OBJECT]
id
path
desc

[LIKES]
obj_id
user_id
timestamp
```

**It would make sence to me to implement a field "nr_of_likes"** in the object table, that will be incremented every time a new row gets inserted in the likes table.
This should be much faster than `COUNT(*)`ing the number of likes per object, right? **The problem is  that I get redundant data, and usually, from what I've studied, that is not good.**
What are some best practices regarding this sort of matter? Can the "nr_of_likes" field be implemented? 
Thank you for sharing your opinions!

Comment: its called de-normalization or memoization, used very often because of performance reasons

Comment: Adding a column that contains the total number of likes to a table as opposed to getting a `COUNT()` is not ideal.  While it may be faster to read, you have to take into consideration that you have to constantly maintain that column every time the number changes.  In addition, you lose all concept of who liked it, and when.  Redundant data is not always bad, but what are you considering being redundant in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to implement a column as you have proposed. As you've also found though, it's usually a bad practice. If you have proper indexing on your `Likes` table then performance will typically be fine. Of course, it depends on exactly how large your database is and what type of system it's on.

Whether or not you want to violate the "general" rule of database design is just like the decision for any other sort of denormalization - what is the reasoning? What costs are associated with that design choice? Do they outweigh the pluses?

My own approach is to always follow standard database design rules. **TEST** for performance before you decide that there might be a performance issue. If you do find a performance issue, look at ways to resolve it (indexing, etc.) without using an inferior database design. Denormalize as a last resort. It's a tool in the toolbelt, just one that is unfortunately used more often than it should be.

Always make sure that you **fully** understand that downsides to the design decision though.